# Angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in AppComponent_Template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue in my Angular application where I'm getting the following error message:

javascript
Copy code
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
This error occurs in my app.component.html file, specifically in the template section where I'm trying to display the name property of an editEmployee object. Here's the relevant code:

```
app.component.ts:

typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees: Employee[] = [];
  public editEmployee!: Employee; // Initialization is done in ngOnInit

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Fetching employees...');
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  // Other methods for adding, updating, and deleting employees...

  public getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (response: Employee[]) => {
        this.employees = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  // Other methods...

  public onOpenModal(mode: string, employee: Employee | null = null): void {
    // Modal opening logic...
  }
}
```

```
app.component.html:

html

<!-- This is where the error occurs -->
<h1>{{ editEmployee.name }}</h1>
```

I've ensured that the editEmployee object is initialized correctly in the ngOnInit method by calling this.getEmployees(). However, when the page loads, it still shows an empty card, and the error appears in the console. Clicking the "Update" button then loads all the data correctly.

I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking the data retrieval logic and confirming that the data is being fetched successfully. I'm now seeking guidance on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it.

Any assistance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Checked ngOnInit: I verified that the ngOnInit method is correctly calling the getEmployees function by adding console logs and breakpoints.

HTTP Request Logging: I logged the response from the HTTP request in the getEmployees function to ensure that data is being fetched from the server.

Template Data Binding: I confirmed that the template is correctly bound to the employees array by adding debugging output to display the data.

Debugging the editEmployee: I added console logs and debugging information to track the editEmployee object to see if it gets initialized.

Initialization of editEmployee: When the page loads, I expected the editEmployee object to be initialized with data from the fetched employee records.

Display of Employee Data: I expected the employee data to be displayed in the template correctly, such as names, emails, job titles, and phone numbers.

No Errors: I did not expect any errors or exceptions to be thrown during the page load or when interacting with the employee data.

Comment: Add the code that initializes `editEmployee`. It's difficult to guess the issue without seeing that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be ChatGPT-generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization is done in ngOnInit...it's okay, but not on the constructor, at least do u need set:

```
public editEmployee: Employee | null = null
```

and on html use something like this

```
<h1 *ngIf="editEmployee" >{{ editEmployee.name }}</h1>
```

isn't the best way, but must be work

FYI:
on ur html ar u using "editEmployee", and this is undefined until u select a employe to be edited

Answer (score 0):

> Initialization of editEmployee: When the page loads, I expected the editEmployee object to be initialized with data from the fetched employee records.
>
> I've ensured that the editEmployee object is initialized correctly in the ngOnInit method by calling this.getEmployees().

No you didn't. You are loading data asynchronously. You started the request and registered the callback to be executed when the data arrives. The function you pass to `subscribe` is executed only after the data arrives.

Compare this to `setTimeout`: the function passed to setTimeout is not executed immediately, but after a specified duration

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('Fetching employees...');
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.editEmployee = {name: 'John'}
  }, 500);
}
```

After `ngOnInit` completes the component is rendered, but your response has not arrived yet - thus `editEmployee` is null.

Note that initializing data in `ngOnInit` is perfectly legal, but in your case, the initialization happens AFTER `ngOnInit`.

To solve, render your component conditionally with ngIf:

```html
<h1 *ngIf="editEmployee">{{ editEmployee.name }}</h1>
```

A common pattern is to show a loading indicator (spinner of what have you) in the opposite case.

An alternative might be [?. operator for optional property accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

```html
<h1>{{ editEmployee?.name }}</h1>
```